# Eclipse error: "This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've recently imported a Maven project into Eclipse, but none of the syntax highlighting is working. Additionally, when I try to write any code to any of the files (`System.out.print("")` for example), a dialog box appears saying "This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project".  This is likely the reason this is happening. How can I fix this?

I've tried the solutions suggested in the following threads to no avail:

["This compilation unit is not on the build path of a java project" -Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731984/this-compilation-unit-is-not-on-the-build-path-of-a-java-project-eclipse)

[Eclipse "this compilation unit is not on the build path of a java project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206572/eclipse-this-compilation-unit-is-not-on-the-build-path-of-a-java-project)

[This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401124/this-compilation-unit-is-not-on-the-build-path-of-a-java-project)

Comment: Do you have these lines in the .project file of the project folder : 
`<natures>
 <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
 <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
</natures> `

Comment: Yes, those two lines are in the .project file.  But the error persists.

Comment: This sounds like you are editing a Java file outside a source folder.